# RegEx выборка и замена ссылок из текста без слеша в конце

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть дамп Базы данных. Нужно заменить все ссылки без слеша в конце на ссылки со слешем в конце. Встречаются ссылки уже со слешем в конце.
Сделал такую выборку

```
(?<=\&quot;)https:\/\/site\.com\/(.*?)(?=(\&quot|\/\&quot))
```

Выражение выше захватывает нужный шаблон как со слешем так и без слеша, а нужно так, чтобы в шаблон не попадали ссылки имеющие завершающий слеш.

```
a href=&quot;https://site.com/dir_contact/&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;пункте самовывоза&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;\r\n  &lt;li&gt;\r\n      &lt;a href=&quot;https://site.com/oplata-chastiami&quot;&gt;Оплата частями&lt;/a&gt;
```

Comment: Добавьте чуть больше дампа - не хватает для тестов вариантов.

Comment: @UModeL там встречается как ссылка с завершающим слешем так и без него, можно просто продублировать кусок несколько раз

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если все ссылки однотипные, т.е. абсолютные (с протоколом и пр.), тогда:

```
/(http[^&]+[^\/])(?=&)/g
```

меняем на:

```
$1/
```

---

В Notepad++:

- Ставим галку на "Регулярные выражения";
- Убираем флаг `g` и ставим галку на "Зациклить поиск".

"Найти:"

```
(http[^&]+[^\/])(?=&)
```

"Заменить на:"

```
$1/
```

Comment: Получилось. Так как условий было больше не добавлял их в вопрос. Окончательный вариант ```(https:\/\/site\.com\/[^&']+[^\/(image|index)])(?=(&|'))```

Answer (score 0):

не легче сделать с помощью if else

```
if link[-1] == '/':
    return
```

Comment: хотелось бы только регуляркой и notepad++
без написания скриптов

Comment: @ОлександрДавиденко: почему в метках не указываете, что для NPP нужно?

Comment: @UModeL не был уверен что это важно, нужно было только само выражение

Comment: @ОлександрДавиденко: некоторые языки могут требовать другой синтаксис.